# Maven/Gradle entries for org.springframework.boot.web.ErrorPage

Tags: java, maven, gradle, spring-boot

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ErrorPage` is deprecated.

So what is the maven/gradle entry for:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.ErrorPage
```

Cannot seem to find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ErrorPage.html), they actually meant "in favor of the superclass, [org.springframework.boot.web.**servlet**.ErrorPage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/ErrorPage.html)", which is located in the same artifact, `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot`.